# How to ignore extra whitespaces after switching to headless chrome

Tags: capybara, google-chrome-headless

Recently I switched my cucumber tests from capybara-webkit to headless chrome. Now many features fail with

> expected to find text "commented by J. Smitch" in "commented by[**two spaces there**]J. Smith"

Is there a way to tell Capybara to ignore extra whitespaces?
Or I need to add whitespaces in my step definitions to make the failing tests green?

**UPDATE 1**

I have `&nbsp;` spaces in my markup which are not normalized like this

```
<div>
  commented by
  &nbsp;
  <span>J. Smith</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that at the same time you switched from capybara-webkit to selenium with headless chrome you also switched from Capybara 2.x to 3.x.  One of the breaking changes in Capybara 3.x is that it attempts to return whitespace more as the user would actually see it. That means that if you have &nbsp; characters in your markup they don't get collapsed with surrounding spaces since the browser doesn't do that. You can use the `normalize_ws` option to get back results more like 2.x

```
expect(page).to have_text('blah blah', normalize_ws: true)
```

however if you're going to the trouble of adding &nbsp;  characters to your page you should probably be checking that the text is displaying with the multiple spaces as you intended.

Comment: No, I am not upgrading from capybara 2 to 3. I just upgraded from capybara 3.5 to 3.11. But I didn't have problem with normalizing whitespaces with capybara-webkit (seems capybara-webkit uses the old strategy with normalizing whitespaces as I had to silence deprecation warnings with normalizing whitespaces). Yes, you are right, capybara 3 doesn't remove browser whitespaces https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/1353

Comment: @Hirurg103 If you were getting deprecation notices around whitespace with capybara-webkit then you weren't using the latest capybara-webkit which was actually compatible with Capybara 3.x - anyway you're going to be much better with Chrome since the JS/CSS support is up to date

Comment: Before moving to headless chrome I was using capybara `v3.5.0` and capybara-webkit `v1.15.0`